# if(!response.error) unit testing using Jest Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, response

Have the following test using **Jest** and **Enzyme**

```
it('Test createAccount function ',async() => {
    wrapper.setProps({})
    wrapper.find('AccountForm').setState({});
    wrapper.update();
    await 
    expect(wrapper.find('AccountForm').instance().createAccount()).toBeDefined()
});
```

Here is the main file **JS**

```
async createAccount(){
    const { user, services } = this.props;
    let AccountBody = { //list of this.states }
    let response = await Models.postAccount({
        user,
        services,
        firmId: FirmId,
        body: AccountBody
    })
    if(!response.error) { 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Not really sure how to approach a unit test in order to test response and its return

```
let response = await Models.postAccount({
```

How could i call response in my test above to make sure the whole function gets tested correctly. I have done similar unit tests in the past but not too familiar when it comes to async/ await and response

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need mock models.postAccounts in your test cases

```
models.postAccounts = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve("YourResponse"))
```

Comment: How could I call the mock above ? what should i include inside of "Response" ...thank you

Comment: In your situation, "YourResponse" will be`{error: false}` to go inside if and `{error: true}` to go inside else

Comment: Models.postAccounts = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(
    {error: false},
    {error: true},
  ))

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but how could I call it ? expect(wrapper.find() ???

Comment: getting the following error:  expect(jest.fn())[.not].toBeCalled()
    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      object: {}

Comment: await expect(wrapper.find('AccountForm').instance().createAccount()).toHaveBeenCalled(modelspostAccounts)

Comment: get the following:  expect(received)[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

    Matcher does not accept any arguments.
    Got:
      function: [Function mockConstructor]